# Export pdf to json

Tags: xml, json, pdf, svg, export

I have a pdf document with word search square table. It looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

I want to have all the words in the word search grid somehow exported into xml or either json format. Is there some software built for this kind of task? 
Or how to build one simle script to do that, is it possible at all?

I used word search software to generate this grid but It has only export as SVG and as PDF.

The thing I want to achieve are: For each word I want the starting coordinates in the grid, maybe also the ending coordinates, or maybe the direction of the word would be good. Can I achieve somehow to export these things into json/xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have thought that working with the SVG version of the export would have been an easier approach.  With a bit of luck the word list will be just a list of `<text>` elements grouped together in part of the file.  From there it would be simple to write a little script to convert those to JSON.

Comment: yup, good point :) Each letter has a text tag and x and y coordinates.

Comment: I checked svg as it is also xml, but It seemed like just pile of tags. Didn't noticed the letters. Each letter in its own one screen wide text tag :)

Answer (score 1):

this might be helpful, it can only only be used on windows and linux

https://code.google.com/p/pdf2json/

Comment: I tried pdf2json -f -xml puzzle1.pfd puzzle1.xml I see no output file in the same folder. What do I miss?

Comment: glad to hear! I've only used this a few times, but let me know if you have any questions

Comment: It exports each word along its x, y coordinates in pixels. Now I have to make a script to convert those coordinates into grid. If no other answers this could be the best, thanks